# ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape when plotting

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

So I have dataframe like this:

[image]

I want to visualize data on Category vs Read Count column with bar chart. If Category is same then it will automatically sums Read Count values, like 'Megapolitan' Category in index 0 and 2. But what I've got right now is an error. This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import pylab as pl
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS

dataset = pd.read_csv('kompas.csv')
dataset.head()

dataset[["Total Comment", "Read Count"]] = dataset[["Total Comment", "Read Count"]].astype('int')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,15))

data = dataset['Category'].value_counts()
data2 = dataset['Read Count'].value_counts() 

category = data.values 
readcount = data2.values

ax.barh(category, readcount) 
ax.set_title('Total Amount of Category on Most Popular News') 
ax.set_xlabel('Total') 
ax.set_ylabel('Category')
```

And this is the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-b28678940ca9> in <module>()
      7 readcount = data2.values
      8 # create bar chart
----> 9 ax.barh(category, readcount)
     10 # set title and labels
     11 ax.set_title('Total Amount of Category on Most Popular News')

4 frames
<__array_function__ internals> in broadcast_arrays(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py in _broadcast_shape(*args)
    189     # use the old-iterator because np.nditer does not handle size 0 arrays
    190     # consistently
--> 191     b = np.broadcast(*args[:32])
    192     # unfortunately, it cannot handle 32 or more arguments directly
    193     for pos in range(32, len(args), 31):

ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because *data* and *data2* variables are not of the same shape.

The [value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) function  returns counts of unique values, this is not what you want for column *Read Count*.

You need to do something like this:

```
category = pd.unique(dataset['Category'])
category_counts = [dataset[dataset['Category']==cat].sum() for cat in category]
ax.barh(category, category_counts)
```